# Не получается открыть проект на отладочном сервере Django

Tags: python, django

При попытке открыть проект на отладочном сервер Django, в браузере вместо открытия проекта сохраняется файл.
Понятие не имею в чем дело, ранее все работало. Откатил все последние изменения, но это не помогло.

Код модуля settings:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-aliw#305&z#1rj4t3zi3hn9@6_qx!e*z872s=jm1b24gp&!-q9'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'news.apps.NewsConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trainingsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trainingsite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Код модуля urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('news.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Код из созданного мною приложения News:**

Модуль models:

```
from django.db import models


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_id = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Модуль views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import News


def index(request):
    news = News.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'news/index.html', {'news': news}, {'title': 'Список новостей'})


def test(request):
    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

Модуль urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index),
    path('test/', test)
]
```

Что я незаметно для тебя сломал?
Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ваш код будет очень полезен, пожалуйста, приложите пример

Comment: а в админку заходит?

Comment: А какой именно файл сохраняется, какое содержимое в нём?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin окно входа в админку открывает. Зайти не могу так как еще не создан суперюзер.

Comment: @andreymal файл открыть не получается. Он весит 1 кб и без названия.

Comment: файл скачивается когда вы переходите по `localhost` или `localhost/test`?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin когда перехожу по localhost. localhost/test открывается в браузере.

Comment: а если `return render(request, 'news/index.html', {'news': news, 'title': 'Список новостей'})` . Если я не ошибаюсь вы должны передавть все значения в 1 словарь. Но вообще странно что скачивается файл, а не выдает ошибку

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Помогло, действительно ошибка была в том, что передавал значения в 2 словаря, а не в 1. Спасибо большое!

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, попробовал открыть через блокнот. Файл открылся, оказалось в нем содержимое созданного мною темплэйта (или это он и есть), в файле html разметка.